# Why doesn't SCP accept the username/hostname combination, when it's accepted by SSH?

Tags: bash, debian, shell, ssh, scp

I use `ssh` to login to Linux hosts through CyberArk, which is the reason for the username/hostname combination: `DB6164@DB6164CP#example.net@y96553.example.net#22@PsmpDblanVip.example.net`

The following `ssh` command works:

```
$ /usr/bin/ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no DB6164@DB6164CP#example.net@y96553.example.net#22@PsmpDblanVip.example.net
```

However, the following `scp` command fails:

```
$ /usr/bin/scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no DB6164@DB6164CP#example.net@y96553.example.net#22@PsmpDblanVip.example.net:/tmp/file.txt file.txt
DB6164@DB6164CP#example.net@y96553.example.net#22: invalid user name
```

If I remove the "#"'s in the hostname, then `scp` stops complaining, but then CyberArk fails.

I've also attempted to use `scp`'s URI form: `scp://[user@]host[:port][/path]`:

```
$ /usr/bin/scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no scp://DB6164@DB6164CP#example.net@y96553.d.net#22@PsmpDblanVip.danskenet.net/tmp/file.txt file.txt
scp://DB6164@DB6164CP#example.net@y96553.d.net#22@PsmpDblanVip.danskenet.net/tmp/file.txt file.txt: invalid uri
```

But that also fails.

Why does `scp` fails, when `ssh` succeeds, and how can I make the above `scp` command work?

**Update**: I need to perform the above for several hosts (connected to through CyberArk).

Comment: Would this help? [scp with special username](https://serverfault.com/q/955058/168875).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scp -o User='foo@bar@baz#quux' host:/rpath lpath

scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -o User='DB6164@DB6164CP#example.net@y96553.example.net#22' \
  PsmpDblanVip.example.net:/tmp/file.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you say why it doesn't work without `-o User`?

Comment: Without `-o User=...` it will try to log in with the same user as on the local machine. When extracting the username from `user@host:/path`, `scp` does a very simple check and rejects any characters in ```[`'"# ]```.

Comment: BTW, ssh accepting `@` in usernames is not ambiguous, because `@` cannot appear in the host name part.

Comment: I see. So, everything after the last `@` is considered the hostname. So, `scp`  successfully extracts the hostname after the last `@`, but gives up on parsing the username and defaults to the local user?

Comment: It's weird, that `scp` and `ssh` don't follow the same rules for parsing the username...

Answer (score 1):

Side-stepping the questions you've raised with a pragmatic solution, you can set up a default mapping for this target, which will simplify it for all `ssh` transport uses.

I'm splitting `DB6164@DB6164CP#example.net@y96553.example.net#22@PsmpDblanVip.example.net` into user `DB6164@DB6164CP#example.net@y96553.example.net#22` and CyberArk proxy `PsmpDblanVip.example.net`, with a final target host of `DB6164CP`. Adjust the example below accordingly, if this isn't correct.

Edit (or create) the file `~/.ssh/config`, and add these at the end of the file:

```
########################################################################
# CyberArk proxy
#
Host DB6164CP
        UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
        StrictHostKeyChecking no
        Hostname PsmpDblanVip.example.net
        User DB6164@DB6164CP#example.net@y96553.example.net#22


########################################################################
# Default
#
Host *
        ForwardX11 yes
        ForwardX11Trusted yes
        Compression yes
        ServerAliveInterval 60
```

You may want to adjust the settings for the default host, since these will be used for every connection that isn't explicitly defined and matched earlier. (The first `Host` section that matches is the one that's used.)

With this configuration in place, you can reference your target simply as `DB6164CP`:

```
ssh -n DB6164CP id
scp -p /etc/hosts DB6164CP:/tmp/my_hosts
```

You can add extra host names and patterns to a `Host` entry, so if you had several targets going through the same proxy host, you could define this

```
Host DB6164CP OTHER*
        UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
        StrictHostKeyChecking no
        Hostname PsmpDblanVip.example.net
        User %r@%h#example.net@y96553.example.net#22
```

And reference the targets like this

```
ssh DB6164@DB6164CP
ssh someOtherUser@OTHERhost1      # Or: ssh -l someOtherUser OTHERhost1
scp DB6164@DB6164CP:file.txt .    # Or: scp -l DB6164 DB6164CP:file.txt
```

You can use `%r` and `%h` as necessary - if you always have a fixed username but variable hosts, put a fixed string in place of `%r` (as for your original question scenario)

Comment: Thank you. Very useful. I just have one issue with this. Say, I've 20 different hosts, do I need to add a single entry to `~/.ssh/config` for each of them? Furthermore, do you know why it doesn't work, when the user and host is given as part of the `scp` command? Finally, why does `ssh` accept two `@` in the user/host combination? Isn't that ambiguous?

Comment: (1) no you can add multiple (space-separated) names and patterns to a `Host` entry. Update your question to explain that you need to do this for several hosts, e.g. `example1`, `example2`... and I'll amend my answer (2) no (3) it doesn't have to be ambiguous - you can use `ssh -l username host:path`

Comment: I've updated my question. I guess `ssh -l username host:path` should be `scp -l username host:path` in your last comment.